# prompt типа: Пароль

Tags: javascript

Вопросв таков:

Как превратить текст prompt'a из type=text в type=password.
К примеру, если зайти на сайт своего роутера (http://192.168.1.1/), то у вас запросят пароль,  но он будет не в текстовом виде, а в скрытом, то-есть круглые точки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё кстати интересно, знает ли кто-то, как сделать чтобы в окно можно было вставить несколько input'ов, как на скрине

Comment: у prompt нет типа «пароль», а то, что ты видишь - специальный диалог basic-авторизации. ты можешь настроить basic-авторизацию на своем сервере или написать аналогичный диалог на html+js(+framework)

Comment: Но это окно меняется в соответствии с браузером, я подумал что это встроенный метод/фукнция в js

Comment: в разных браузерах этот диалог имеет визуальные различия, функциональных отличий же нет. твоё предположение не верно, я объяснил выше